# A 1980 kids sci-fi series with robot puppets; not anime

Tags: story-identification, tv, robots

All the robots are different. No animation, just "muppets". No humans (well in my memories) just those robots with some who wants to rebel I think.

I remember fake grass, robots made of different grey plastics. Really weird series.

Feels like UK or Australian; was translated into French because I watched it in Quebec when I was a kid.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what did the robots *do*? Why were they hanging around on the grass? Did they have names? Did they have weapons? Why were they rebelling? Who were they rebelling against? Did they have vehicles?

Comment: Sounds like [Dick Spanner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Spanner,_P.I.)

Comment: A variant of Spanner was used in [adverts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IshbmtZrJo) too.